# Make accidentally opening an app on the Dock more difficult

Tags: macos, dock, mouse, click

I always open a program accidentally by clicking too fast within the Dock.

I thought that maybe I am the only one having this problem, but my spouse recently got a Mac and keeps complaining about the same issue.

This is especially annoying if you have programs who need some loading time like Photoshop or Office.

Is there any way to configure macOS to open programs only with a double click from the Dock?

Comment: You cannot change the click rate in different areas of the screen; it's a global setting.  Try ***hiding the dock***.  This way, you have to hold your mouse in the area for a second for the dock to appear.

Comment: This doesn't help as I already have the dock hidden. This happens when trying to switch from one app to another and it seems that a lot of users have the exact same problem without ever having found a solution.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - how can you "accidentally" open something that's already open?  Do you mean accidentally *switch* to it?  If that's the case, then I have to ask "why are you clicking on it?"

Comment: please see https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21548/how-would-you-solve-the-accidentally-launching-problem-of-the-mac-os-dock

Comment: Based on what I read from that link and at the risk of sounding flippant; *slow down*.  The UI functions exactly as intended

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the Dock, which then requires hovering the mouse at the bottom of the display for the Dock to be shown first, then clicking on an app. To hide the Dock, right-click on the Dock separator and choose Turn Hiding On.

Comment: I have already hidden the Dock. This doesn't solves the problem as it appears when I try to switch from one app to another.